# Відповідник до слова "екстрим"

Tags: вибір-слова, відповідник

Екстрим — екстраординарні дії, пов'язані з небезпекою для життя. Також є екстримальні види спорту, екстримали та екстримальні ситучації або умови.

Цікавить чи є відповідник в українській мові для "екстирму" або ж чи його можна утворити, щоб він зберіг значення цього слова. На [Словотворі](https://slovotvir.org.ua/words/ekstrym) пропонують варіант "межовництво", однак він не є підтвердженим. Крім того, хоч "екстрим" походить від "extremus" — "межовий", мені здається сьогодні це слово більше асоціюється із небезпекою для життя. Тому, можливо, слово "небезпека" і є відповідником до слова "екстрим"? Тоді отримаємо "небезпечні види спорту", "небезпечна ситуація", однак як бути в такому випадку із словом "екстримал"?

Answer (score 1):

Хоча не всі мовознавці довіряють **СУМ-20**, але слова ***"екстрим"*** та ***"екстремал"*** в ньому присутні, тому нормативні.

> ***[ЕКСТРИМ](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=199678&page=861)*** у, ч. **1.** Сукупність будь-яких дій, пов'язаних з відчуттям небезпеки, ризиком і т. ін. *Маршрути в карстових печерах
>   різні за рівнем складності. Якщо екстрим не лякає, кожен може взяти
>   участь у розвідуванні нових ходів* (із журн.); *Унікальний ландшафт
>   Присамар'я – живописні озера і стариці, сфагнові болота і заплавні
>   луки, солончаки і піщані дюни – спокушає любителів автоперегонів по
>   пересіченій місцевості, які шукають екстрим* (з газ.).
>   **2.** розм. Надзвичайна ситуація, подія, переживання і т. ін. *Погода інколи підносить нам такі сюрпризи, які спрогнозувати неможливо.
>   Травневий екстрим не зміг передбачити ніхто* (із журн.).
>
> ***[ЕКСТРЕМАЛ](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=185048&page=861)*** а, ч. Той, хто вдається до надто ризикованих дій
>   спортивного характеру, трюків, отримуючи задоволення. *“Чому Африка?”
>   – згадався їй рекламний слоган українських екстремалів .. Євка не
>   допускала й миттєвого жалю за комфортом* (І. Карпа); *З цієї вантової
>   конструкції на Черепановій горі ризикують стрибати хіба що екстремали
>   – трамплін нестійкий і здригається навіть від вітру* (з газ.).

**[Орфографічний словник української мови](http://slovopedia.org.ua/35/53397/77455.html)**

> **екстрема́л**  іменник чоловічого роду, істота  людина, що займається екстремальними видами спорту

Отже, слова  ***"екстрим"*** та ***"екстремал"*** можемо сміливо використовувати у всіх видах мовлення.